# Android Mediation integration with inmobi , mopub

Tags: android, admob, mopub, inmobi

i have integrated Admob Mediation as below

```js
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
  mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(mAdListener);

InMobiAdapterExtras inMobiExtras = new InMobiAdapterExtras();
MoPubExtras moPubExtras = new MoPubExtras();
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
 .addNetworkExtras(moPubExtras)
 .addNetworkExtras(inMobiExtras)
 .build();

mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

it shows ads live (app is in store now) since a month but doesn't showing any impression count
am I doing any thing wrong with this code

Comment: Where doesn't it show any impression count? And where are you providing your AdUnitId?

Comment: @ william it shows me ads on device but wont show impression on admob official account panel i have updated code section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with mediation api problem remain same after getting response from mediation team

I have ended up using separate integration of inmobi and mopub without mediation
rather then wasting hours in checking response from mediation team.